# Apply brush settings to all unmasked areas?

Tags: sculpting, masking

For example, if have the inverse of a mask over a particular area. I don't feel like drawing over the space because it can make some uneven spots. Is there a way I can just apply a brush with all it's settings to all unmasked areas instantly?